# fgetcsv() with two delimiters

Tags: php, database, function, csv, fgetcsv

So, I have the following function using fgetcsv.

```
 public function CSVtoArray($value) {
      $row = 1;
      $file = "tmp/tmp.csv";
      file_put_contents($file, $value);
      if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
           $data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");
           fclose($handle);

           return $data;
      }
 }
```

The function takes csv input as such "something, something". The problem I've been having is that it keeps the *space* **after** the **,**. I figured I could just add ", " too the delimiter, but it only takes one delimiter. I double check the documentation, and it'd seem that there isn't a workaround for that.

I know StackOverflow isn't a code gen service, but I'm stumped. Is there anyway too remove the spaces after the **,**? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: the input csv is unquoted?

Comment: @Dagon Yes, the input _is_ unquoted.

Comment: array_walk with trim on the output is an option

Comment: @Dagon That seems like it'd do perfectly well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
return $data;
```

to:

```
return array_map('trim',$data);
```